# Python - bad gateway error based on API limit

Tags: python, api, urllib, ckan

I am trying to retrieve data from a CKAN API URL:

```
import urllib.request
import json
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://data.gov.il/api/3/action/datastore_search?resource_id=dcf999c1-d394-4b57-a5e0-9d014a62e046&limit=1000000'
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
    html = response.read()
    result = json.loads(html)
    df = pd.DataFrame(result['result']['records'])
```

But getting the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-8484123eecdc> in <module>
      2 import pandas as pd
      3 url = 'https://data.gov.il/api/3/action/datastore_search?resource_id=dcf999c1-d394-4b57-a5e0-9d014a62e046&limit=1000000'
----> 4 with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
      5     html = response.read()
      6     result = json.loads(html)

~\miniconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
    220     else:
    221         opener = _opener
--> 222     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    223 
    224 def install_opener(opener):

~\miniconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    529         for processor in self.process_response.get(protocol, []):
    530             meth = getattr(processor, meth_name)
--> 531             response = meth(req, response)
    532 
    533         return response

~\miniconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in http_response(self, request, response)
    638         # request was successfully received, understood, and accepted.
    639         if not (200 <= code < 300):
--> 640             response = self.parent.error(
    641                 'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
    642 

~\miniconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in error(self, proto, *args)
    567         if http_err:
    568             args = (dict, 'default', 'http_error_default') + orig_args
--> 569             return self._call_chain(*args)
    570 
    571 # XXX probably also want an abstract factory that knows when it makes

~\miniconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    500         for handler in handlers:
    501             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
--> 502             result = func(*args)
    503             if result is not None:
    504                 return result

~\miniconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
    647 class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
    648     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
--> 649         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    650 
    651 class HTTPRedirectHandler(BaseHandler):

HTTPError: HTTP Error 502: Bad Gateway
```

Interestingly, if I use lower limit in the URL, e.g.:

```
url = 'https://...&limit=10000'
```

everything works fine. If I use no limit at all, it only retrieves the first 100 records.
Can anyone please explain why this is happening? Is this some server-side restriction? How can I go around this, so I can get the whole data set, regardless of how many records are included (there are frequent updates adding more records)?
Also, is this the right way to fetch data from a CKAN API? If not, I'd be glad to see how this should be done.

Comment: The API documentation should call out a limit if there is one.  I'm fairly certain there is a limit.

Answer (score 0):

There are some limitations on CKAN api, if you need to query more that 100 records you need to set an offset and query as many times you need, like pagination.